# OSX - Canopy cannot be shutdown

Tags: macos, enthought, canopy

I am running OSX 10.3.1 and I am unable to fully shut Canopy down, or restart it. When I last shut Canopy down, the windows shut down as normal, but Canopy was (and is) still shown as a running application in both the dock and the 'Force Quit Applications' window, though in neither does it respond to a 'Force Quit' command. Clicking on the 'Canopy' dock object does not restart Canopy. Canopy is not listed as a running application in Activity Monitor, and there are no instances of Python running, nor any other tasks that could obviously be linked to Canopy. My OSX Python is 2.7. Could Canopy be masquerading under another name in Activity Monitor or running a task not called Canopy, Enthough etc? Or can anyone suggest a means of shutting Canopy down? I would like to restart it.

all the best,
Jeremy

Comment: a) What version of Canopy? (The current version is 2.1.6).

Comment: b) Canopy only calls itself Canopy or Python. I would suggest rebooting your machine.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer.I cannot be sure of the Canopy version (I cannot start it to find out) but it is fully up-to-date.

Comment: Sorry, finished the comment prematurely. After some thought I found a way to get the Canopy version without starting Canopy. It is 1.7.4.3348, not 2.1.6. I probably should plan to upgrade, but that still does not account for the problem in killing Canopy. I cannot start Canopy by clicking on the Canopy app object, but if I open that object and go to 'app data', then canopy-1.7.4.3348.macosx-x86_64 there is another Canopy.app object from which I can start another instance of Canopy. I still cannot kill the original Canopy, but the new instance seems to work. Thanks for the fast response, Jeremy

Comment: Sounds fragile! Reboot!

Comment: I went into a terminal window and did a `kill -9` on the process named 'canopy'.  Now there are no processes named 'canopy', but Canopy still shows up in the "Force Quit" list.  And clicking it has no effect.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue - Canopy was closed but wouldn't quit from the terminal, the activity monitor or even the opt-cmd-esc 'force quit applications' window. It wouldn't let me uninstall from applications because canopy was still open even after deleting all the files in the app. Finally, and most annoyingly, it wouldn't let me shut down my computer conventionally because canopy was 'open' and wouldn't force quit.

In the end I just had to smother the computer off (as in old school keep the off button pressed down and ignoring any popups till it was off), after which the mac restarted itself, and then then I could delete the existing shell of an app and re-install the latest version of canopy. Couldn't tell you what the root problem is but canopy works just fine now (if not better as I have the newer version).